# JQuery masked input question

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, mask

I need to make a text field with masked input, and an input mask should change dynamically depending on the first digit of a city code.

Example masks:

```
+7 ### ### ## ##
+7 #### ## ## ##
```

By default (while no digits entered), it is possible to use the first mask.

I've tried to do it in this way (with JQuery and Masked Input Plugin):

```
$("#p_phone_number").mask('+7 999 999 99 99');
$("#p_phone_number").click(function(){
  if ( $(this).val().substr(1,4) == "+7 9"  ) {
    $("#p_phone_number").mask('+7 999 999 99 99');
  } else {
    $("#p_phone_number").mask('+7 9999 99 99 99');
  }
});
```

But it doesn't work correctly (place digit not under cursor, etc.).
Can you give me an advice with this situation?

Comment: Where is the dynamic change above?

Comment: @dmirkitanov: I need to do something similar, changing a phone mask to allow either (999) 999-9999, 999-999-9999, or 999.999.9999. Did you ever find a working solution?

Comment: @Otis No, I didn't really. The library definitely had bugs at that time, but it might have been updated.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up just allowing any of the characters in the 3 formats and then validating the input matched one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing ...

```
$("#p_phone_number").click(function(){
```

... into ...

```
$("#p_phone_number").keypress(function(){
```

`Click()` should only catch mouse button events, which - by the sound of it - isn't what you want.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work too.. Plus, after any input cursor is placed at the end of string.

Comment: Sounds like Mask doesn't like being dynamically called then ... you may have an evil hack on your hands.  It sounds pretty evil to me anyway.  Good luck!